# How to make do a if statement with class in it(java)

Tags: java

I want to return back into the main menu but instead of making a millon return buttons i want to do a if statement which says that if class method=all these classes it would return back to the main menu, how would i do that?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class How_wants_to_be_a_millionaire extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame start_Frame, help_Frame, quit_Frame, bstart;
    Container bstartCon, helpCon, thisContainer3, thisContainer4, thisContainer5, thisContainer6;
    JPanel centerPanel, southPanel, northPanel, midPanel, topPanel, downPanel, quitup, quitdown, donateup, donatedown, helptop, helpdown;
    JButton start_button, help_button, quit_button, extra_button, return_bs;
    String L1 = "Welcome to the Game!";
    String L2 = "This a multiple choise game, player would have a question and 4 choises, only one is the correct one";
    String L3 = "When players reache a certent amount of money, they could choose to leave or continue playing";
    String L4 = "When players choose to continue playing,";
    String L5 = "The money beyond that point will not be saved until it reaches the next check point";
    String L6 = "Player have 3 assist that could help, they could only used once, they are 50:50, Phone assist and addience assist";
    String L7 = "50:50 eliminates 2 false answers, Phone assist is to call anyone in 30 sec to help you,";
    String L8 = "Addience assist is to perform a vote live to give a preferce of what people think the answer is";
    JLabel help_Line = new JLabel ("<html>" + L1 + "<br>" + L2 + "<br>" + L3 + "<br>" + L4 + "<br>" + L5 + "<br>" + L6 + "<br>" + L7 + "<br>" + L8 + "</html>");
    Font font = (new Font ("Font", Font.PLAIN, 14));


    public void before_we_start_menu ()
    {
        bstart = new JFrame ("How Wants to be a millionaire?(Guide Menu)");
        bstart.setBounds (100, 100, 450, 150);
        bstartCon = bstart.getContentPane ();
        bstartCon.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        midPanel = new JPanel ();
        midPanel.setBackground (Color.BLACK);
        topPanel = new JPanel ();
        topPanel.setBackground (Color.BLACK);
        downPanel = new JPanel ();
        downPanel.setBackground (Color.BLACK);
        bstartCon.add (midPanel, "Center");
        bstartCon.add (downPanel, "South");
        bstartCon.add (topPanel, "North");

        start_button = new JButton ("Start");
        start_button.addActionListener (this);
        topPanel.add (start_button);

        help_button = new JButton ("Help/Rules");
        help_button.addActionListener (this);
        midPanel.add (help_button);

        extra_button = new JButton ("Extra");
        extra_button.addActionListener (this);
        midPanel.add (extra_button);

        quit_button = new JButton ("Quit");
        quit_button.addActionListener (this);
        downPanel.add (quit_button);

        bstart.setVisible (true);
        bstart.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public void help ()
    {
        help_Frame = new JFrame ("Help/Rules");
        help_Frame.setBounds (350, 350, 500, 350);
        helpCon = help_Frame.getContentPane ();
        helpCon.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        helpdown = new JPanel ();
        helpCon.add (helpdown, "South");
        help_Line.setFont (font);
        helpCon.add (help_Line);
        return_bs = new JButton ("Back");
        return_bs.setFont (font);
        return_bs.setForeground (new Color (0xffffdd));
        helpdown.add (return_bs);
        return_bs.addActionListener (this);
        help_Frame.setVisible (true);
        help_Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }



    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getSource () == help_button)
        {
            help ();
            bstart.setVisible (false);
        }
        if (event.getSource () == quit_button)
        {
            System.exit (0);
        }
        if (event.getSource () == return_bs)
        {
            before_we_start_menu ();
            if (class=help ())//This is where i wanted help
                help.setVisible (false);
        }
    }





    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        How_wants_to_be_a_millionaire c = new How_wants_to_be_a_millionaire ();
        c.before_we_start_menu ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some example and what exactly is not working or what you want, as above is not clear.

Comment: The condition `class=help()` contains three errors: (1) You cannot use a keyword (class) except according to Java syntax. (2) Assignment (=) is very likely false, do you want to compare (==) something. (3) help() is void and therefore does not represent a value. - Can you describe which condition you want to test here?

Comment: i wanted to create just one return button which return to the menu, how would i set the visible to false when the methods are all different

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I get the question right and you want to provide specific functionalty to all classes of a given type - you can probably have those classes implement a "marker" interface, and then let your code check if the calling class is instanceof that market.

Comment: I doubt that this is in any way related to OPs problem.

Comment: Which might be the case, but it would make more sense for whoever asked the question to say so (or downvote the answer based on "doubts").

Comment: Which of the classes in the question should implement this interface? And what is a "market" interface anyway? Did you mean "marker"?